# SAS macro with help option

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to create a macro with help option also like below:

```
%macro now(gg,datas); 

%if &gg=help %then  %do
%put; 
%put %str(hello);
%goto exit;
%end;
proc print data=&datas; run; 
  %mend;
```

So when I call the macro with help

```
%now(help)
```

the following should be printed

```
hello
```

in the log, but instead it doesnt do anything. What is wrong in this code?

Comment: You may want to consider switching to use keyword parameters instead of positional parameters.  As written, to call the macro without invoking the help mode, you would need to code `%now(,sashelp.shoes)`  note the comma at the beginning, to give the gg parameter a null value.  This would quickly become annoying to remember.  With keyword parameters, you could call with `%ow(datas=sashelp.shoes)`. Actually, even though it's defined with positional parameters you can still call with keyword parameters.  But I think better to define with keyword parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a semicolon after the `%do`, and you've referred to a label called `exit` in your `%goto` statement which doesn't exist. These errors prevent the macro from being compiled, so when you attempt to call it, SAS does nothing (apart from generating a warning message in the log, unless you've disabled those).

The following should work as you expect:

```
%macro now(gg,datas); 

%if &gg=help %then  %do;
%put; 
%put %str(hello);
%goto exit;
%end;
proc print data=&datas; run; 
%exit:
  %mend; 

  %now(help)
```

I would suggest using `%return` for this sort of thing rather than `%goto` - you get the same sort of functionality without having to define labels and worry so much about the flow of your macro.